# What does this seg fault mean

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, binaryfiles

I have a segmentation fault when i run my C program and i do not understand it.
I am reading the header from a binary file that contains student structs.

this is the seg fault i get when i run it with gdb

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804850f in main () at aidb.c:49
49      }

I am under the impression that the segmentation fault is at line 49, however there's only the closing bracket of my main () method at line 49.
This is my code, just in case it helps clarify things:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char id_chars[4];
    int file_size;
    int section_table_offset; 
    int section_count;
} Header;


typedef struct {
    int offset;
    int num_entries;
    int type;  // legal value above
} SectionHeader;


    int main(void) {


      FILE *infile = fopen("file.bin", "r");

      Header aidbheader;


        //Reads the aidb file header
       // fread(aidbheader, sizeof(Header),16, infile);
       fread(&aidbheader.id_chars, sizeof(char),4, infile);
       fread(&aidbheader.file_size, sizeof(int),1, infile);
       fread(&aidbheader.section_table_offset, sizeof(int),1, infile);
       fread(&aidbheader.section_count, sizeof(int),1, infile);

       SectionHeader table[4];
       fread(table, sizeof(SectionHeader), 48, infile);


      printf("\nSectionHeader offset: %d \n", table[3].offset);




      return 0;
    }   // this is line 49
```

Comment: `int id_chars[4];` --> `char id_chars[4];`, `fread(table, sizeof(SectionHeader), 48, infile);` : `48` --> `4`

Comment: Check if your infile is NULL.

Comment: Crashes on the closing bracket of a function (and in general on `return` statements) are usually due to overwriting of the function return address, which is often caused by going out of boundaries of local arrays.

Comment: You never call fclose.

Answer (score 3):

You declare `table` as:

```
SectionHeader table[4];
```

Then you try to read into `table` 48 objects of size `sizeof(SectionHeader)`.

```
fread(table, sizeof(SectionHeader), 48, infile);
```

There isn't enough space in `table` to hold that much data. Because of that, you write over memory that you are not supposed to. That is cause for undefined behavior. In your case, the undefined behavior manifests as segmentation fault when the program returns from `main`.

You can fix that problem by changing the size of `table` or changing the `fread` line. Make sure that `table` has enough space to read the data.

The other error in your code is that the `id_chars` member of `Header` is defined as:

```
int id_chars[4];
```

When you read data into it, you are using

```
fread(&aidbheader.id_chars, sizeof(char), 4, infile);
```

This by itself won't cause segmentation fault. It is a symptom of possibly buggy code. Make sure to change the definition of `id_chars` to

```
char id_chars[4];
^^^ char  not int
```

or change the `fread` line to use:

```
fread(&aidbheader.id_chars, sizeof(int), 4, infile);
                                  ^^^^ int not char
```

Comment: i changed int id_chars[4] to char id_chars[4] but i still get a seg fault. There is only suppose to have about 4 headers, which is the reason i have SectionHeader table[4]; Will giving it a bigger size cause it to read data it is not supposed to? The data i need should be coming right after the 4 SectionHeader objects

Comment: thanks alot @BLUEPIXY your answer was the solution to my problem. Thanks guys.